# How to improve my Entity Framework , to join several database queries into single query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following ActionFilter class, to implement my custom authorization system:-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
string ADusername = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
            if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,Action)) 
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You cannot access this page");

            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

The above class will call the following repository method:-

```
   public bool can(string user, string Model, string Action)
            {
                bool result;
                bool result2;
    int size =tms.PermisionLevels.Where(a5 => a5.Name == Action).SingleOrDefault().PermisionSize;
    var securityrole = tms.SecurityroleTypePermisions.Where(a => a.PermisionLevel.PermisionSize >= size && a.TechnologyType.Name == Model).Select(a => a.SecurityRole).Include(w=>w.Groups).Include(w2=>w2.SecurityRoleUsers).ToList();

    foreach (var item in securityrole)
                        {
    result = item.SecurityRoleUsers.Any(a => a.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower());
    var no = item.Groups.Select(a=>a.TMSUserGroups.Where(a2=>a2.UserName.ToLower() == user.ToLower()));
    result2 = no.Count() == 1;
    if (result || result2) {
        return true;
    }}
    return false;
    }
```

But inside my repository method , I am doing the following:-

1. Query the database and include all the Groups & SecurityRoleUsers when executing the .tolist()
2. Then filter the returned records insdie the server, based on the foreach loop.

But this will cause the following drawbacks:-

1. If I have many Groups and SecurityRoleUsers, then I will be getting them all from the DB, and then filter the result on the server.
2. And since this code will be executed whenever an action method is called, as it Is a security attribute at the begging of the controller class. So this might not be very efficient.

So my question is whether I can join all the queries inside the repository method to be single query , and do all the work on the Database and just return true or false to the server ?
The associated tables looks as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ideally remove this foreach.
Try riding with Linq to Sql.
You should be more comfortable because it resembles SQL.

This link has several examples.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Att

Julio Spader

[wessolucoes.com.br](http://wessolucoes.com.br)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but can you explain your point. if i remove the foreach, what will i write instead?

Answer (score -1):

Use linq.
Ideally you should only have one line of code after you got the size value. e.g.

```
int size =tms.PermisionLevels.Where(a5 => a5.Name == Action).SingleOrDefault().PermisionSize;

var result = //One line of code to determine user authenticity

return result;
```

I think you should design you database in the way that join queries are easy to do. So you don't have to perform more than one select.

Try code-first EF, which links tables very easily.

Comment: but my question is how i can join all the quries into a online code .. this is my question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take care with Lazy Loading. If not used correctly, it will make a query to the database each object segmentation, especially in your foreach. With that already has a good improvement.

Take a look at this article. I think it will help you too.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/entity-framework-performance-optimization/

Att

Julio Spader

[wessolucoes.com.br](http://wessolucoes.com.br)

Comment: but i am including all the navigation properties before performing the Tolist()... so they will not be any lazy loading !!!!!!!!!!